# Organize and push data in array to REST API with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to push some props, the props are related to products, i need to push the props in an array (products) instead of pushing all the props separated.

In my HTML i have some props that i need to push if exists to API :

```
<div id="app"
    data-product="Premium Pack"
    data-sku="454677-rEqO3"
    data-image="https://2_RB_3183_006_71.jpg"
    data-website="https://website.com/"
></div>
```

Here is how i push the props :

```
if( typeof this.props.product !== "undefined" )
    data.push({ key : 'product', value : this.props.product });

if( typeof this.props.sku !== "undefined" )
    data.push({ key : 'sku', value : this.props.sku });

if( typeof this.props.image !== "undefined" )
    data.push({ key : 'image', value : this.props.image });

if( typeof this.props.website !== "undefined" )
    data.push({ key : 'website', value : this.props.website });
```

I am trying to refactor the code above like this, but i don't see how to organize the data in an array :

```
this.props.string.forEach( string => {
    let value = string.value;
    let name = string.name;

    if( typeof this.props.name !== "undefined" )
        data.push({ key : name, value : value });
});
```

I have managed to push the props using for...of loop, the problem is that i still can't organize the elements in a products array and i cant exclude some props, this gets all the props :

```
if( typeof this.props.product !== "undefined" ) {
    const obj = this.props;
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
        data.push({ key : key, value : value });
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show the examples of the data format you are trying to achieve, i dont understand what you mean by `organize the element in a products array`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `Object.entries` to convert the props into an array of `[key, value]`s and map it to an array of `{key: name, value: value}`s:

```
const data = Object
.entries(this.props) // will create an array of [key, value] s
.map(([key, value])=> ({key, value})) // will create a array with {key: name, value: value} s
```

If you didn't quite understand what is a `Object.entries` or `array.map`, you can look docs of this methods:

- [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)
- [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: yes i have checked the Object.entries, if u could re-check the question

Comment: so you just want to check if your props are not undefined before pushing them into the data?